# Better way to say "repeat sequentially"

Tags: phrases, synonyms, phrase-requests

I'm trying to say "it counts the number of times a given value repeats sequentially" in a list, meaning it finds the maximum number of times a value occurs *in a row* in a list.  I know there's a word for it, but I can't remember it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Repeats sequentially** is the wrong expression, as OP suspects. The normal phrasing would be...

*It counts the number of times a given value appears* **consecutively**.

Comment: ... or "appears consecutively".

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: It's a *very* fine (possibly non-existant) distinction, but I have the feeling I prefer *appears* in respect of multiple instances, and *occurs* if there's only one or a very small number. So thanks, and I'll edit to reflect that! :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:
 
'(Occurs) one after another'?

… or, perhaps the word you're looking for is 'consecutively'?

EDIT: as FumbleFingers beat me to it, here's something more elaborate (perhaps not what you want):

"It shows the quantity a given value repeats itself consecutively".

Comment: I think "repeats [itself] consecutively" is at least somewhat tautological, in that repetion is implicit in anything consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

The computerese term I would use is "recur."